# Error in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure / cursor execution in asp.net using C#?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

Hello this is my first cursor program that I have written.

I am surprised to see the error after successful affecting the rows of table in my procedure that I want to do using this procedure.

I am assigning the menus to the post and when I remove some menu from specific post then I need to update (Add/Remove) menus to all employees belonging to this post. This below procedure does all things but I am getting an error :

> *Error:There is already an object named 'EmployeeMenuMst' in the database.*

after execution.

Stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sUpdateEmpMenuMst]
    (@EmployeePostID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @EMPID INT
    DECLARE @EMPMENUID INT

    BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE EmployeeTable CURSOR FOR

    SELECT EmployeeID FROM EMPLOYEEMST WHERE EmployeePostID=@EmployeePostID

    OPEN EmployeeTable

    FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeTable INTO @EMPID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM EmployeeMenuMst WHERE EmployeeID=@EMPID  

    FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeTable INTO @EMPID
    END
    CLOSE EmployeeTable
    DEALLOCATE EmployeeTable

        SELECT   EmployeeMst.EmployeeID, EmployeePostMenuMst.MenuID, EmployeePostMenuMst.AccessLevelID,1 AS ISVISIBLE
        INTO EmployeeMenuMst
        FROM     EmployeePostMenuMst 
        INNER JOIN EmployeeMst 
        ON EmployeePostMenuMst.EmployeePostID = EmployeeMst.EmployeePostID
        WHERE EmployeeMst.EMPLOYEEPOSTID=@EmployeePostID ORDER BY EmployeeMst.EMPLOYEEID
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity INT
        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)

    END CATCH

   END
GO
```

In code behind `aspx.cs` file:

```
private void UpdateMenus()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "sUpdateEmpMenuMst";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePostID", Convert.ToInt32(Session["postID"]));
            cmd.Connection = con;
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

The error is on `ExecuteNonQuery` line. Why does it throw an error - any idea?

And after getting error rows are affected successfully in the way that I need!

Help appreciated!

Comment: is 'EmployeeMenuMst' being created with each run of the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   EmployeeMst.EmployeeID, EmployeePostMenuMst.MenuID, EmployeePostMenuMst.AccessLevelID,1 AS ISVISIBLE
        INTO EmployeeMenuMst
```

Will try to create a table EmployeeMenuMst ans fill ist, perhaps you are searching for

```
Insert into EmployeeMenuMst
SELECT   EmployeeMst.EmployeeID, EmployeePostMenuMst.MenuID, EmployeePostMenuMst.AccessLevelID,1 AS ISVISIBLE
```

Comment: How to return the value of rows affected to ExecuteNonQuery in code behind file. Now the code runs fine but i am getting here -1 value even after affecting the rows.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE That sounds like a different question - please consider opening a separate one/searching on here as bummi has already answered your original problem.

Comment: k thanks @bummi for replying i have modified above query now it works fine!